# Creating user defined errors in Java; why does this code not work?

Tags: java, exception

```
import java.util.*;
class ArrayOverflowException extends Exception{
    ArrayOverflowException(){
        super(); 
    }
    static int i;
    static void check(int i) throws ArrayOverflowException{
        if (i>5) {
            throw new ArrayOverflowException("Array Overflow");
        return;
}
}
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner input=new Scanner(System.in);
    int a[]=new int[5];
    System.out.println("Enter the elemets of the array. #MAX 6 ELEMENTS#");
    try{
        for (int i=0;i<10;i++) {
            ArrayOverflowException.check(i);
            a[i]=input.nextInt();
        }
    }catch (ArrayOverflowException e) {
        System.out.println("Exception handled"+e);
    }
}
}
```

I have been trying to create my own user defined exception in Java that gives an error `cannot find symbol in line 9` . Please help.

> Line 9 is throw new ArrayOverflowException("Array Overflow");

Comment: change it to `for (int i=0;i<10;i++) {`

Comment: I have already tried doing that and it didn't make a difference

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) add constructor with string param

```
ArrayOverflowException(String message){
    super(message); 
}
```

2) remove return, it's unreachable code

```
return;
```

Also check if you want to check i or value from user input?

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 problems here:

1. You need to create a constructor that accepts a `String` parameter:

   ```
   ArrayOverflowException(String message) {
       super(message);
   }
   ```
2. You can't `return` after `throw`, since it immediately jumps to the nearest `catch` block, which in this case is outside the method.